Change Drupal Hostname
I did something stupid and updated apache, php, and mysql before i had a chance to upgrade drupal.  Once I saw it was too late, I couldn't revert because it would break other updates.  I got the novel idea of mysqldumping to a second server and made the unfortunate error of putting into foobar.com/drupal.  Because I was incrementally upgrading I didn't want to mess other things up.  THen i redumnped, re-imported, and then I noticed I can't remove foobar.com/drupal because it is all in the root foobar.com.
How do I remove the subdirectory?  It seems I can't find any file when grepping or searching the tables besides some cache tables.  Drush seems to crash for no reason too.
How do I fix this?

you can just copy and paste the drupal folder and paste it in htdocs or equivalent directory.
